# Jetty 6 to Jetty 9 Context Deployer migration

Tags: jetty

Migrating from Jetty 6 to 9 has been much harder than what I originally thought but I have got a lot of it done thanks to the resources you all have online

I question that I have not found xml examples online regarding Embedded Servlets in Jetty 9 other than the link below

http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Jetty-9-Context-Deployer-td4960157.html

First off, it seems that you all have migrated from ContextDeployer to WebAppProvider is this a correct statement?

I ask this because in Jetty6, I was able to use a context deployer to search a directory to configure servlets as context objects.  Since ContextDeployers seem to be gone, the closest usage in Jetty I see is the WebAppProvider which opens webpages from a war file.  This isn't what my company wants to do and we would like to be able to use contexts in the same way we have done in the past

Now I have seen the ServletContextHandler which seems simple enough to configure and would act as the context object.  However, my current web app provider configuration will not open my servlet web pages

Here is an excerpt of how I use the DeployManager in xml

```xml
<Call name="addBean">
<Arg>
  <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
    <Set name="contexts">
      <Ref refid="Contexts" />
    </Set>

    <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
          <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="config/jetty/context/"/></Set>
          <Set name="scanInterval">5</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

An example Servlet configuration xml

```xml
<Configure id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Call name="addServlet">
    <Arg>class.name.here</Arg>
    <Arg>/*</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Where would your servlet classes be loaded from?  Are they context specific? or server specific? (There's no hint how you did this in Jetty 6, as it would also have the same classloader concerns)

Comment: You mention embedded servlets in the question and have tagged embedded-jetty, but your question seems from the point of view of the jetty distribution and the xml configuration.  which form are you using?

Comment: The latter, I am using xml configuration which is something I don't think I can stray away from. Sorry for the confusion. My knowledge of jetty is growing but its still pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WebAppProvider in exactly the same way that ContextDeployer was previously used.   Specifically if you put a context.xml file into the webapp directory, it will be hot deployed exactly as it was with the ContextDeployer.

As for the type of the Context you wish to deploy, it an be just a ContextHandler, a ServletContextHandler, a WebAppContext or anything else that extends ContextHandler

Look in the demo-base/webapps directory for some examples.

In your example, I'm guessing that the id="contexts" might be the problem.  Try removing it as you don't need an id there.  Other than that, it looks like it should work, so you are on the right path.